# Kurento combining multiple video streams into one

Tags: kurento

The specific problem I am trying to solve is that I have two webcams with one audio source that I want to have stream side-by-side, but I am not sure how to do that in kurento.

Ideally a viewer would come to view my stream and only see one video which is the mixture of two videos side-by-side.

I know that in javascript I can add multiple streams to a peer connection, or even add video tracks to the primary stream, but how I can split those streams or use them side-by-side on the kurento side of things.

Also, I know that ffmpeg has things like -filter_complex which can combine two video streams into one side-by-side stream and I would like to do that same. This way viewing the recordings for both webcams and audio can be done in one file instead of multiple which would have to be served up together and synced up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `composite` media element, which will combine up to nine streams into one stream. This media element has, however, some limitations right now

- All the streams will have the same size
- The size of the combined stream is always 800x600
- Each client will receive the combined audio from all other clients, but not his own audio. That is important if you are going to connect a recorder
- There is a [reported bug](https://github.com/Kurento/bugtracker/issues/6) that we are working on right now

Comment: Is this mature now?